# What is the difference between the study of Evolutionary algorithm vs. Optimization?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I have a course named "Evolutionary Algorithm". But, our teacher is always mentioning the word "Optimization" in his lectures.

I am confused. Is he actually teaching Optimization? If yes, why is the name of the course not "Optimization"?

What is the difference between the study of Evolutionary algorithm and Optimization?

Comment: Just because a word is mentioned frequently in a lecture doesn't mean the lecture is (only) about that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in evolutionary algorithms, you are optimizing an objective function. Hence, evolutionary algorithms are algorithms for optimization. Hence, they are the specific case of optimization methods. However, there are a vast variety of optimization methods that are not an evolutionary algorithm (such as simplex methods in OR, Lagrange methods and so on). See more about the evolutionary algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm):

> In artificial intelligence, an evolutionary algorithm (EA) is a subset of evolutionary computation[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm), a generic population-based **metaheuristic optimization algorithm**.